# How can i get the two different image objects intersection point while they are animating in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, animation, frame

I need the solution for this problem.  `Image` Objects(fruits images) are animating from top to bottom just like snow fall. I need to catch that `image` objects using another `image object`(basket image). So, I want to find out the basket image and fruit image intersection point. but I didn't get the intersection point .I used

```
CGRectIntersectsRect(fruitObjPresentationLayer.frame, basketObjPresentationLayer.frame);
```

to find out the intersection point..

Comment: have u passed the updated frames to this function.

Comment: im getting (fruitObjPresentationLayer.frame.x and .y values as null..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CGRectIntersectsRect() returns a bool not the intersecting points.  So when they do intersect compare the frames position to each other and then do the math to figure out where the intersection is.

Also, frames are rectangles so there their intersecting point will actually be a line, not a point.

You could set up a NSTimer to fire, say, 60 times a second to call

```
if ([CGRectIntersectsRect(fruitObjPresentationLayer.frame,    basketObjPresentationLayer.frame)] {
//when this is called do whatever you want with the objects current frame.origin
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`CGRectIntersectRect` is a function which returns you the `boolean` value, if collision occurs between two objects whose frames you are passed to this function.
In your case you need to passed the updated frame of both objects. As per your question, the objects are animating from top to bottom means the frames of both objects are changed at runtime. So you needs to calculate the `frame` of current position of both objects and then passed that updated `frame` to the `CGRectIntersectRect` function. Try to pass the updated frames to the `CGRectIntersectRect` which solves your problem.

For calculating the updated values you must needs too find out the delta values like

```
deltax = currentposition.x-previousposition.x;
deltay = currentposition.y-previousposition.y;
```

then update the `frame` of both objects as

```
CGRect Frame = obj1.frame;

    Frame.origin.x+=delta_x;
    Frame.origin.y+=delta_y;
```

similarly for second `object`.

Comment: please suggest me, how to find out the updated frames of image objects  while animating..

Comment: @user1882447 please find my updated answer I had edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for ur immediate response..But using this code also i need to caliculate the updated frame values.using updated frame values only i get the current postion and previous position of  images..how can i caliculate the previous position and current position